# Is the Drush backend API a web-accessible API? How does one install it?

Tags: drush

I've successfully configured Drush 4.5 to work agains my Drupal 6 site from the command line using site aliases.  I am doing things like sql-sync and rsync successfully from the command line.  What I'd like to do now is expose these functions over the web, through an API.  The Drush documentation leads me to believe I can do this, however it is somewhat lacking in details on how to accomplish this, or indeed whether it's even part of the intended design.

There is a very high chance that I have completely misunderstood the documentation and have assumed a CLI-only API was designed to be available through the web.  However, the backend.inc file talks about a REST API accessible over HTTP and is ambiguous about what this API actually does.

> This is nearly a RESTful API. @see htp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST
>   Instead of "http://[server]/[apipath]/[command]?[arg1]=[value1],[arg2]=[value2]"
>   it will call "[apipath] [command] --[arg1]=[value1] --[arg2]=[value2] --backend"

It's not clear to me what this actually means, because it says "instead of" the web call, but then goes on to describe how GET and POST arguments differ and how they are passed in from a web call.

> If the Drush API is meant to be called over the web, e.g. http://server.com/drush/drush.php/drupal-directory?argv1=@staging how do I enable this, given that Drush is in a separate PHP source tree?  Do I symlink to it from my Drupal directory?  Do I copy or symlink an include file and expect Drupal to pick it up?

Answer (score 4):

As the previous respondents said, drush is a cli tool.  If you would like to invoke Drupal functions via web services, try the [services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module.  If you would like to manage multiple Drupal sites via a web ui, try [aegir](http://drupal.org/project/hostmaster).

If you would like to call drush functions remotely from php:

`$values = drush_invoke_process('@alias', 'drush-command', $args_array, $options_array);`

See `examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php` for examples on how to make an alias record.  Instead of '@alias', you can also pass in an array containing the site record definition, or you can use `username@myserver.com/path/to/drupal#mysite.com`.  See the source code comments in drush for an explanation of drush_invoke_process, and the contents of the $values array.

Answer (score 3):

According to the comments/functions at the top of drush.php it's a CLI only tool. It evens goes so far as to kill the script if it's not accessed specifically via the command line.

```
if (!drush_verify_cli()) {
  die('drush is designed to run via the command line.');
}

...

function drush_verify_cli() {
  return (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' || (is_numeric($_SERVER['argc']) && $_SERVER['argc'] > 0));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of the documentation in Drush's `backend.php` is that it compares Drush `--backend` with a REST server to explain its behavior. Drush is not a web application or a REST server and is CLI only.

Since version 3, Drush support direct execution of commands on remote host over SSH:

```
drush username@myserver.com/path/to/drupal#mysite.com status
```

Answer (score 1):

This module could provide a web-accessible API for Drush, though it does not use the backend API: https://drupal.org/project/drushweb